# Passing a nested array element result into a @Binding

Tags: swift, binding, state

My title is probably terrible. This is one of those too hard to title questions.

```
extension Color {
  static let availableForSelectionColors : [Color] = [.red,.blue,.green,.yellow]
}
```

I have a view

```
    struct myView: View {
            
            @Binding var bgColor : Color
    
               var body: some View {
               
                        VStack { 
                             ...
                         }.background(bgColor)

 }
}
```

That I create instances and set the background color of in a `ForEach` Loop.

```
struct myOtherView : View {

 @State private var storedColors : [Int] = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"key") as? [Int] ?? [0,1,3,1]
 @State private var bgColor = Color.red

 ForEach((0..<100), id: \.self) { index in
    myView(bgColor: $bgColor)
   }
 }
```

However I want to set the color using `availableForSelectionColors` based on the `storedColors` index in the `ForEach` loop. I.e

```
...
ForEach((0..<100), id: \.self) { index in
        myView(bgColor: Color.availableForSelectionColors[storedColors[index %4]])
       }
     }
```

but can't because `Color.availableForSelectionColors[storedColors[index %4]]` is not a `@Binding`

[image: Errror]

How then to make `Color.availableForSelectionColors[storedColors[index %4]]` `@Binding` so I can pass in to create `myView`. I have used Binding as user can change the array in `UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey:"key")` in a modal sheet which should be reflected back in `myView`

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear why `myView` needs to take a `Binding` and can't just take a `Color`, so just to be sure: is there a reason you need a `Binding`?

Comment: I tried to keep question as code free a possible. Will update. However I've used a Binding because user can change the color in another view.

Comment: You can make a constant binding with .constant(...)

Comment: If I use .constant(...)  then changes to my UserDefaults won't be reflected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Binding` yourself based on each index. It would look something like this (if I correctly understood what you're trying to do):

```
func colorBinding(for index: Int) -> Binding<Color> {
   .init(
      get: { Color.availableForSelectionColors[storedColors[index]] },
      set: { storedColors[index] = Color.availableForSelectionColors
                                        .firstIndex(of: $0)!}
   )
}
```

This function returns a `Binding<Color>`, and the binding is bound to the specified element in the `storedColors` array, except it converts between the `Color` and the `Int` index in the `Color.availableForSelectionColors` array.

So, you can use the return value of the function directly as a parameter to `myView`:

```
ForEach((0..<100), id: \.self) { index in
   myView(bgColor: colorBinding(for: index % 4))
}
```

---

<sub>`!` is used as a simplification, as I assume that the only colors that could be used are those in the `Color.availableForSelectionColors` array; obviously, it would crush if a different color is used.</sub>